# SQL Server - Create Index on query over multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indices

I'm having big problems with optimizing a specific SQL-Query. It contains multiple inner joins and adding indices to each table doesn't improve performance at all.

My query:

```
declare @categoryid  int = 2;

SELECT  [Scanresultebay].Id
        , [Scanresultebay].Productebayid
        , [Scanresultebay].Price
        , [Scanresultebay].Stockamount
        , [Scanresultebay].Timestamp
        , [Category].Categoryname
        , (
            SELECT TOP 1 [Scanresultebay].price
            FROM    [Scanresultebay]
                    INNER JOIN [Productebay] ON [Productebay].id = .[Scanresultebay].productebayid
                    INNER JOIN [EbaySeller] on [EbaySeller].id = [ProductEbay].ebaysellerid
            WHERE   [dbo].[EbaySeller].id = 28
                    and [ProductEbay].categoryid = @categoryid
            ORDER BY [Scanresultebay].Id DESC
        ) AS 'OurPrice'
FROM    [Scanresultebay]
        INNER JOIN [Productebay] ON [Productebay].Id = [Scanresultebay].productebayid 
        INNER JOIN [Category] ON [Category].Id = [Productebay].categoryid 
WHERE   [Scanresultebay].productebayid in ( 
            SELECT  [Scanresultebay].productebayid
            FROM    [Scanresultebay]
                    INNER JOIN [ProductEbay] ON [ProductEbay].id = [ScanResultEbay].ProductEbayId 
                    INNER JOIN [Category] ON [Category].Id = ProductEbay.CategoryID 
            WHERE   [ProductEbay].categoryid = @categoryid  and [ProductEbay].expired is null 
            GROUP BY [Scanresultebay].ProductEbayId 
        )
        and [Scanresultebay].Id in (
            SELECT  max(Id)
            FROM    [Scanresultebay]
            WHERE   productebayid = [Scanresultebay].ProductEbayId 
                    and [Scanresultebay].Price <> 0 
            GROUP BY [Scanresultebay].[ProductEbayId]
        );
```

My Index (as SQL Server suggested me):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ind_GetPrice]
ON [dbo].[ScanResultEbay] ([Id],[ProductEbayId]) include ([Stockamount], [Timestamp],  [Price])
```

I need this query for displaying infos on a dashboard on my website. So I have to loop through each category (100 in total) with this query. This lasts up to 30-40 seconds, which is too much of course.

Creating a view is a problem, as I have to declare the parameter of categoryid for subqueries aswell and parameters can't be passed to a view.

So my questions:

1. Can I do a specific index just for this query, so it gets a lot faster (now it takes 0,5sec).
2. Is my query too long (or ineffective) due to those subqueries?
3. What can I do else, to improve my performance?

Comment: The first thing to do is look at the execution plan. One tip I can give you is try to change the `in` operators to `exists` operators.

Comment: just want to rule out parameter sniffing:
please add option (recomple) at the end of query and let us know

Comment: for me it seems like CARDINALITY ISSUE..
can you materialize your 2 IN condition in TEMP TABLE if the data is not huge?

Comment: there is a field named `productebayid` here and there without any prefix. what's the table that field is coming from? also alias the tables: having the same tables in a query used in multiple places without aliases can lead to unexpected issues due to differences between your interpretation and the optimizer's one

Comment: @Paolo thank you for your edit, I updated it with the correct table aliases.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I don't really get the syntax of exists. Because if I don't exactly tell which column should be in the return of my subquery, I'm getting like 8000 rows back.

So whats the equivalent of "and [Scanresultebay].Id in (...)" of exists?

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma Adding "OPTION(RECOMPILE)" didn't improve the query unfortunately. 
I have no expierence with creating temporary tables, but my data is changed permanently, so are temporary tables the right thing to look after?

Comment: @zvaenr temporary table populate and destroy every time user calls the store procedure, if there is any cardinality issue in your query (which can be find out by looking in the query execution plan )  than that will be resolved BUT U have to  take care that how much data you are dealing with these temp table that should not be much.
without looking into execution plan all are only guessing.

Comment: We need to see the query plan.  Preferably the Actual, but even the estimated would be helpful.

Comment: The way the above is wirtten it should not have any trouble with parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not a full answer**, but an answer to your question in the comments about the exists syntax.
instead of:

```
WHERE   [Scanresultebay].productebayid in ( 
        SELECT  [Scanresultebay].productebayid
        FROM    [Scanresultebay]
                INNER JOIN [ProductEbay] ON [ProductEbay].id = [ScanResultEbay].ProductEbayId 
                INNER JOIN [Category] ON [Category].Id = ProductEbay.CategoryID 
        WHERE   [ProductEbay].categoryid = @categoryid  and [ProductEbay].expired is null 
        GROUP BY [Scanresultebay].ProductEbayId 
    )
```

use this:

```
WHERE   EXISTS ( 
        SELECT  1
        FROM    [Scanresultebay] t1
                INNER JOIN [ProductEbay] ON [ProductEbay].id = t1.ProductEbayId 
                INNER JOIN [Category] ON [Category].Id = ProductEbay.CategoryID 
        WHERE   [ProductEbay].categoryid = @categoryid  
        AND [ProductEbay].expired is null 
        AND [Scanresultebay].productebayid = t1.productebayid
    )
```

Note that I've moved the `[Scanresultebay].productebayid` from the where clause of the main query into the where clause of the inner query. `Exists` will evaluate to `true` of the query inside the parenthesis returns results, otherwise to `false`.

Also, The last `in` operator should be replaced with `=`, since `select SELECT  max(Id)` will only ever return a single value.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to rewrite this query to something like this (this is only proof of concept using [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)):

```
declare @categoryid  int = 2;

with products_a as (
    select  [scanresultebay].productebayid
                from    [scanresultebay]
                        inner join [productebay] on [productebay].id = [scanresultebay].productebayid 
                        inner join [category] on [category].id = productebay.categoryid 
                where   [productebay].categoryid = @categoryid  and [productebay].expired is null 
                group by [scanresultebay].productebayid 
    ), -- 1st from where clause
    products_b as (
    select  max(id) id
                from    [scanresultebay]
                where   productebayid = [scanresultebay].productebayid 
                        and [scanresultebay].price <> 0 
                group by [scanresultebay].[productebayid]
    ), -- 2nd from where clause
    items as (
    select  [scanresultebay].id
            , [scanresultebay].productebayid
            , [scanresultebay].price
            , [scanresultebay].stockamount
            , [scanresultebay].timestamp
            , [category].categoryname
    from    [scanresultebay]
            inner join [productebay] on [productebay].id = [scanresultebay].productebayid 
            inner join [category] on [category].id = [productebay].categoryid 
    )
    select
        items.*
    from    
        items 
        join
            products_a
        on
            products_a.productebayid = items.productebayid
        join
            products_b
        on
            products_b.id = items.id
    ;
```

It eliminates `IN` and, by splitting the query, it makes easier to check/optimise partial queries.

I could not run it, so there could be minor mistakes.

It doesn't contains the part about price -- I didn't catch the joins you use,
but I would use something like that (as part of query above):

```
select id,
[scanresultebay].productebayid,
price,
row_number() over (partition by [scanresultebay].productebayid order by [scanresultebay].id desc) nr -- top price is nr = 1 per each [scanresultebay].productebayid
from    [scanresultebay]
        inner join [productebay] on [productebay].id = .[scanresultebay].productebayid
        inner join [ebayseller] on [ebayseller].id = [productebay].ebaysellerid
where   [dbo].[ebayseller].id = 28
        and [productebay].categoryid = @categoryid
```

I assumed that `[scanresultebay].productebayid` is the key for join.
Query above (after adjustment) can be added to first query above and joined
in final query.

I lack of good tool for format and syntax check, so please forgive any errors above.

Answer (score 0):

You should create indexes for each foreign key.

If your where clause includes multiple fields for a single table then you should create indexes on these combinations also.

edit:

To elaborate:

1. Indexes are global. Not query specific.
2. 100 categories is extremely small.  You have a lot of joins (all are necessary)
3. Create the indexes it will improve performance massively!